# linkage of c++ const globals?

Tags: c++, linkage

I have 5 files:
a.h:

```
extern const int a;
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
const int a = 1;
```

b.h:

```
extern const int a;
extern const int b;
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
const int b = a + 1;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
int c = a + 1;
int d = b + 1;
int main() {
  printf("c: %d\n", c);
  printf("d: %d\n", d);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile them with the following order:

```
gcc -c *.cpp
gcc a.o b.o main.o -o after
gcc main.o a.o b.o -o before
```

When I run `after` and `before`:

```
./after
c: 2
d: 3

./before
c: 2
d: 1
```

Someone else can explain the linkage of these globals?

Comment: A great argument for not using globals.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a global `const` has internal linkage, but you've nullified it with the `extern` declarations so `a` and `b` have the external linkage that you want. (If they didn't, your program wouldn't link!)

However, due to [the static initialisation order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order), you don't know what order those constants are going to be initialised in. They'll be top-to-bottom within a translation unit, of course, but across translation units all bets are off. You're able to observe some of those shenanigans by altering the link order.

Try to avoid code like this; [various approaches exist](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use) for your redesign.

Comment: If the OP's real variables are of built-in type, and are initialized with a simple literal, then the simple fix is to write `const int a = 1;` in `a.h` and then b.h is `#include "a.h"` and `const int b = a+1;` - sadly of course, the OP has probably pared a complex problem down to its essentials (for which I shall up-vote them).

Comment: @MartinBonner Indeed